# Json alternative to Docusign connect XML

Tags: docusignapi

We are trying to determine if there is a way to obtain the timestamp of when a Carbon Copy, "Envelope Signed" or "Envelope Completed" email is sent with a json api instead of xml.

We have tested using Docusign connect by selecting the "Envelope Signed" and "Envelope Completed" events under "Send information on these envelope events" in the Docusign console.

Also, when the document is signed, we receive the expected post request to our connect endpoint which includes the following (private info removed) and are wondering if the timestamp in the "Sent" tag means that the carbon copy email was actually sent at that time and therefore we can use it for auditing purposes.

```
<RecipientStatus>
  <Type>CarbonCopy</Type>
  <Email>bob@example.com</Email>
  <UserName>Bob</UserName>
  <RoutingOrder>2</RoutingOrder>
  <Sent>2015-07-08T16:14:18.88</Sent>
  <DeclineReason xsi:nil="true" />
  <Status>Completed</Status>
  <RecipientIPAddress />
  <CustomFields />
  <AccountStatus>Active</AccountStatus>
  <RecipientId>dc9521c4-b11d-426c-b409-326b985e823b</RecipientId>
</RecipientStatus>
```

thanks
PR